# Looping through dataframe names and plotting in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe of 12 variables and I'd like to plot exactly one variable against others using ggplot's `geom_point()`. Wouldn't want to do it manually so i need to loop through the variables making plots.
For example, I have a df like this (simplified to 4 variables for readability):

```
> head(df)
letters    value1    value2    value3
A          1         0         10
B          3         1         9
C          6         0         8
D          76        0         7
E          13        1         6
F          58        1         5
```

And I'd like to produce two plots where `value1` is plotted over `value2` and `value3`.
I've tried this:

```
plts <- vector()
for (i in names(df)) {
  p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=value1, y=i, fill=letters)) + geom_point())
  plts <- append(plts, p)
}
```

but it treats the values 2 & 3 different than the value 1 and produces something like this (e.g., value1 over value3):
[Plot of value1 over value3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twmAA.png)

What should be done to improve this and achieve the goal of having the plots like this:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=value1, y=value3, fill=letters)) + geom_point()
```

[Produced without a loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FnxdH.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using `aes_string()` instead of `aes` will give you what you want.  Your problem is caused by the tidyverse's use of non-standard evaluation ([NSE](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html)).

```
lapply(
  names(df),
  function(y) {
    df %>% ggplot() + geom_point(aes_string(x="value1", y=y, colour="letters"))
  }
)
```

giving, for example

[image]

You can customise the first argument to `lapply` to select the variables you need.

That said, I think it would be easier and more robust to reformat your data frame to a more helpful layout and then create your plots...

For example,

```
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols=c("value2", "value3"), 
    names_to="Variable", 
    values_to="y"
  ) %>% 
  ggplot() + 
  geom_point(aes(x=value1, y=y, colour=letters)) + 
  facet_grid(rows=vars(Variable))
```

Giving

[image]

By the way, using `colour=letters` is probably more informative than `fill=letters` when using `geom_point`.

Comment: `aes_string` is getting deprecated.  You may also mention `!!sym` route